# Azure Dev Ops not sending email notifications

Tags: azure-devops, tfs

I'm having an issue that since we switched to Azure Dev-ops I do not get email notifications from the platform. I've asked other people on my team and some get notifications others don't, the notifications were put together as defaults for the repo, so I don't understand why it works for some people?

[image: Notification Active]

[image: Notification Definition]

Comment: From the screenshot that shared, it is a global notification triggered by the event `Reviewers added or removed` to send emails to PR `creator` and `changed reviewers` rather than every member in your `Project Collection Valid Users` group. May I know if you added new reviwers to a PR and some of them failed to received emails about this change?

Comment: You may also go through the steps in the [document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/organizations/notifications/troubleshoot-not-getting-email?view=azure-devops) to rule out possbile causes.

Comment: I was added as a reviewer to a PR and did not receive a notification. Most of the possible causes aren't applicable because I know that other people on my team are receiving notifications

Comment: Hi there, may I know if you added **yourself** as the reviewer of this PR? If yes, this is expected, because you are the `initiator` of this event and the notification to the event `initiator` is **skipped**. For the others who are not the event `initiator`, they should be notified. Would you mind asking others in your team to add/remove you as/from a PR reviewer for a test please? Hope the information could help sort out the root cause and good luck.

Comment: Hi there, may I know the latest status of the issue and if notification was skipped for the initiator? Thx.

Comment: It seems to be working now. I'm not sure if that's because I changed the email to a different alias or something else. There were PRs that other people created that were not reaching me